# Regex: Match only characters with preceding lowercase letter(s)

Tags: regex

I'd like to clean up a subtitle file that has many errors because of OCR. On of the errors is that the `l` is displayed as `I`. Of course sometimes the `I` is really a `I`, mainly in the case of:

- The beginning of a sentence: `I'm Ieaving...` or `- I'm Ieaving...`.
- In names: `IsabeIIe`.
- Maybe a few weird cases.

Since names are difficult to detect, I figured it would be best to replace only the `I`'s with one or more directly preceding lowercase letters and check the rest manually. So after the conversion I get `I'm Ieaving` and `Isabelle`. This is the most 'barebone' automated solution I can think of since there are not that many words that have a lowercase letter directly preceding an uppercase letter.

How can I do this in Regex? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookbehind, you can find all I's preceded by a lowercase letter like this:

```
(?<=[a-z])I
```

Otherwise, you could match both characters, and the second one will be the I.

```
[a-z]I
```

Comment: This answers the question, but @KeyMs92 hasn't thought this through. You should also look for an uppercase I following another uppercase I (and probably also other uppercase letters). Think `IsabeIIe` and `BIuetooth`.

Comment: You're right, but I have thought this through. As I mentioned, I'm trying to find a barebone automated solution that avoids mistakes. Only looking for preceding lowercase letters is then pretty much the minimum. Broadening the expression will get rid of `BIuetooth` but introduce e.g. `DlY`. Anyway, thanks for your answer, it totally works!

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these, and if your engine supports modifier groups.

```
(?-i:(?<=[a-z])I)
or
(?-i:[a-z]I)
```

For Unicode, you will want to use properties.

Answer (score 0):

`/([a-z])I/` would capture upper case I's preceded by any lowercase letter a-z.